# Ubuntu 16.04 OpenVPN

Tags: vpn, openvpn, 16.04

When I choose the Connection Type in VPN Connections, I have only PPTP and I can't find OpenVPN, but I already installed it via terminal with the command `sudo apt-get install openvpn easy-rsa`

Why I can't find it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

To get the VPN connection to show up in Network Manager, ensure that all these packages are installed:

```
network-manager-openvpn
network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-vpnc
```

It may be overkill but it works.

Even with this, it worked a little flakey on 16.04.  One of my PCs threw an error when I tried to open the .ovpn file.  I had to configure it manually. On a different PC it worked OK.

Comment: Seemes like exactly  network-manager-openvpn-gnome is missing. I remember in 14.04 it was automatically installed as a dependency.

Comment: Doing `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome` should pull in `network-manager-openvpn` and `openvpn` as dependancies.

Answer (score 0):

For "plain" Ubuntu 16.04 (Unity-based) installing `network-manager-openvpn` should be sufficient. For Ubuntu GNOME install `network-manager-openvpn-gnome`, it will pull the other one as a dependency. The PPTP package is unnecessary, it's a completely different protocol than OpenVPN.

So for regular Ubuntu:

```
apt install network-manager-openvpn
```

For Ubuntu GNOME:

```
apt install network-manager-openvpn-gnome
```