# "error: the plugin does not support import capability" when attempting to import openvpn config file

Tags: network-manager, 16.04, openvpn

Gnome network manager can't import any openvpn config file (.ovpn) after upgrading ubuntu to 16.04 version;

I get the following error message 
when I try to import openvpn config file:

```
The file 'file-x.ovpn' could not be read or does not contain recognized VPN connection information Error: the plugin does not support import capability
```

Comment: This has been resolved and answered here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/760664/ubuntu-16-04-openvpn?lq=1

Comment: Hi Kestrell ...Thank you  for your answer*************
I already installed  required packages and successfully setup openvpn manually:
**********but my problem is that i can't import openvpn config files using network manager

Comment: Did you ever get this working?

Comment: before reading any more, check that network-manager-openvpn is installed.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### My setup

I also had the same issue, trying to import on an Ubuntu 16.04 client a `.ovpn` file produced by a home pritunl server.

The .ovpn file contained comment lines (`#`) as well as inline certificates (`<ca>`, `<tls-auth>`, `<cert>`, `<key>`). And there was no apparent reason to remove comments or keys. This same `.ovpn` had already been successfully imported into the Kubuntu 16.04 network manager, with only a warning about `reneg-sec` being too high; A clue to import issues on Ubuntu 16.04.

### Solving the OP's errors

1. The `reneg-sec` value is too high and encounters known [import bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365):

   ```
   reneg-sec 2592000
   ```

   Comment it out or use default value `3600`.

   ```
   #reneg-sec 2592000
   ```

   This value can be re-set from `Advanced` settings in `VPN` config tab under:

   [image: reneg-sec]
2. The config had two `remote` definitions:

   ```
   remote hostname.org 14195 udp6
   remote hostname.org 14195 udp
   remote-random
   ```

   Try with only one:

   ```
   #remote hostname.org 14195 udp6
   remote hostname.org 14195 udp
   #remote-random
   ```

After these two modifications, there were no import errors.

### Further issue with `remote` configuration

Although there was no import error any more, the remote was not imported properly, i.e. the port and protocol were not properly parsed, so I had to further break the `remote` directive down in the .ovpn file as follows

```
    remote hostname.org
    port 14195
    proto udp
```

### Summary

My .ovpn file contained comments as well as inline certificates, etc.. After reading some other posts, I thought the problem lied in the inline files or the comments, so I split the inline certificates and keys into separate files and removed all comments.

**So in the end, after applying the above fixes, the `.ovpn` file with the inline keys and comments was imported.**

Comment: Thanks the `reneg-sec` value is the reason I could not import my `.ovpn` file. There is a network-manager bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365

Comment: Thanks, I also had to check "Use LZO data compression" in the advanced options of Network Manager (I use OpenVPN Access Server). And be careful of DNS leaks! Without firewall rule to block DNS queries on the Ethernet / WiFi interface, there was a DNS leak, even when using my own DNS server IP and with "block-outside-dns" rule for OpenVPN 2.3.10 (via Network Manager). You can check for DNS leaks on the website https://www.dnsleaktest.com/ and double check with a tool like Wireshark.

Comment: Splitting the certificates in other files allowed me to import successfully. I also had to use `tls-remote` instead of `verify-x509-name` for it to work

Comment: Googling, it seems there are MANY MANY reasons why the file could not be parsed. Isn't a way to get a more verbose message on what caused the parsing error trying to import the `.ovpn` file ?

Answer (score 34):

The issue for me was the following line in my `.ovpn` file:

```
route remote_host 255.255.255.255 net_gateway
```

Commenting out this line allowed me to import the connection.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 and still had this issue. Commenting this line out (from Sophos XG config) fixed it.

Comment: ubuntu 19.04 same issue, commenting out this line fixed error

Comment: Same is true for ubuntu 19.10 (also Sophos .ovpn config).

Comment: Also applies to Ubuntu 20.04.01 LTS

Comment: Also applies to Lubuntu 21.04 hirsute

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 18):

I also have Ubuntu 16.04, and the same problem occurs.
The solution is not a very good solution, because you need another computer already connected with the VPN.

Check that you have already installed openvpn and network-manager, from the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
$ sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

In general, this should work, but in very few cases (and i don't know why - i suppose that's probably a bug) a `.ovpn` can't be imported.

So, follow theses steps:

1. On the computer that already have a created connection with the VPN, select the vpn connection
2. make empty the password
3. click on export button

At this point, you'd have a ".conf" file.

4. open the ".conf" file and edit any parts that reference files on your computer if exists
5. In your computer, create a new connection with the ".conf" file.

Comment: that happened to me as well. Luckily I had a laptop already configured and could use that trick to configure my new computer. Quick note though: I had to configure username, password, key file and advanced TLS key file again.

Answer (score 9):

Try adding it through the terminal instead of through the GUI:

`sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file your-file.ovpn`

As stated on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-openvpn/+bug/606365

PS: You might still need to tweak your .ovpn with the tips found on other answers on this question nevertheless.

Comment: No Need to change anything on the config file; it is saved my time

Answer (score 7):

```
$ sudo openvpn --config file.ovpn
```

worked for me - I can tunnel, however I need to remember local IPs since I have no local DNS configured.

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was necessary to remove all the comments (starting with #) from the *.ovpn. Some people found also that the line containing "remote SERVER NNNN" should be split into "remote SERVER" and "port NNNN".

Comment: I can confirm that removing the comments from the `.ovpn` file resolved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

## Edit *.ovpn file

Probably this is caused by settings in the `.opvn` file that can't be parsed.

First make sure you have the needed packages installed:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-openvpn openvpn
```

If it still fails, edit the *.ovpn file in a text editor and strip out the following lines that break the import.

## `<he>` tag

If there is a `<he>` tag in the client ovpn config files, delete those lines.  It's not needed:

```
<he>
...
</he>
```

## Multiple connection details

If there is something like:

```
<connection>
remote <ip> 443 tcp-client
</connection
<connection>
remote <ip> 1194 udp
</connection>
```

Replace that section with this:

```
remote <ip> 1194 udp
```

The import stumbles upon multiple connections and doesn't support the `<connection>` tag. At least not in 16.04-17.04.

That's all, IMHO you can keep comments, they make no difference.

After you deleted the  tag and edited the connection part, try to import the modified *.ovpn file. [Solution](https://dev.webonomic.nl/setting-up-openvpn-on-ubuntu-fixing-import-errors) from this blog post.

Comment: This was it for me!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install. To my surprise openVPN was NOT installed by default.

I figured out because when I clicked "+" sign in "setting->Network->VPN"section the dialogue box did only had two option i.e. Open VPN option was not there.

I followed [1](https://askubuntu.com/a/801008/1071039) and installed openvpn and restarted network manager everything worked fine after that as I can see the OpenVPN option on the popup [image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e44QJ.png)

```
sudo apt install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome
sudo systemctl restart network-manager
```

[Joao Paulo's advice](https://askubuntu.com/a/801008/1071039)

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to change the following in the .ovpn file:

```
remote ***.org 443 tcp-client
```

To:

```
proto tcp
remote ***.org 443
```

And also, as pointed by @Kostas Filios I had to change this part to a comment:

```
#reneg-sec 2592000
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while importing the .ovpn file with the network manager.
I fixed it by changing my remote line from

`remote vpn.example.com 1190 udp4`

to

`remote vpn.example.com 1190 udp`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to replace the line `remote xx.xx.xx.xx 443 tcp4` with `remote xx.xx.xx.xx 443 tcp` for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

All the tags should be removed. Tags like

```
<connection\>
</connection\>
<ca\>
</ca\>
```

Sometimes, the commenting doesn't work. Address the certificate to the file in which you store it.

```
 ca '/home/mersadkhan/.cert/nm-openvpn/su2-tcp-ca.pem'
```