# "Use custom gateway port" unchecks itself after saving when configuring OpenVPN

Tags: 16.04, vpn, openvpn, raspberrypi

I have OpenVPN set up on a Raspberry Pi that is connected to my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS laptop via ethernet cable.  I used the utility `scp` to copy the following files from `/etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/keys`:

`tetra5.crt` 
`ca.crt`
`tetra5.key`

I then went to VPN Connections->Configure VPN->MyVPN->Edit to fill the following information in:

[image]

Under the VPN Tab, I clicked Advanced and went to the General tab, and entered the following:

[image]

I then click Okay, and then click Save on the screen of the first image, in order to save the configuration.

I'd like to make mention that even with saving the configuration, everytime afterwards when I go back to the second image, the "Use custom gateway port: 1194" is unchecked.

In any case, I go to connect to TetraVPN and get the following message: "The VPN connection 'TetraVPN' failed because the connection attempt timed out"

Could anyone please provide some insight as to why this is occuring?

Comment: You may need to directly modify configuration file (**.ovpn**). See: http://askubuntu.com/questions/760664/ubuntu-16-04-openvpn **(answer)**