# Error when loading OpenVPN config file

Tags: openvpn

Openvpn service on my laptop, version `OpenVPN 2.4.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`, cannot load the `.ovpn configuration file`; error details as snapshot below.

The file works well for `OpenVPN 2.3.3` on my colleague laptops with Ubuntu Desktop 14.

So I want to install 2.3.3 for Ubuntu Desktop 17, and my [google search](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=openvpn+2.3.3+installation+for+ubuntu+desktop+17&oq=openvpn+2.3.3+installation+for+ubuntu+desktop+17&aqs=chrome..69i57.15966j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) is little helpful.

Any idea to workaround? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the file name is correct? If it is, then something might be wrong with the content of the file. So, what is the content. Double check the file that works is identical to the file that doesn't.

Comment: About the file content, I have tested on Ubuntu Desktop 14 and it works.

Comment: The filename to be in the formation of `my-username@sub-domain.main-domain.com.ovpn` - how to tell if it is correct? I also have other files with the extention to be `.ca.crt`, `.user.crt`, and `.user.key`

Comment: Check the answer to this question and make sure you have all those plugins installed. https://askubuntu.com/questions/760664/ubuntu-16-04-openvpn/760679#760679

Comment: Thank you! I'll try apt install `network-manager-openvpn-gnome
network-manager-pptp
network-manager-vpnc`

Comment: I tried installing the packages you mentioned but the error still remains @OrganicMarble

Comment: I got the error saying `Error: Key file contains line "client" which is not a key-value pair, group, or comment`

Answer (score 1):

For us, we use custom port and tcp.  I found that if I removed the protocol and port used after the remote ip address, this helps.  you would have to enter it manually but it saves a lot of time from manually building the entire profile.

For instance, within the .ovpn file...since we use custom a custom port and TCP:
remote x.x.x.x 1187 tcp
Remove "1187 tcp" and save.

This worked for me.

You might be using some other custom config within the file that the program doesn't like.  try removing these and adding manually after the file is accepted.