# VPN Options Not Here

Tags: command-line, networking, vpn

I am attempting to install a vpn. When I try to install it via network connections there is no option for vpn just pptp. It also can not connect when I enter it in pptp. Thanks

Comment: See if the answer to this question helps you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/760664/ubuntu-16-04-openvpn/760679#760679

Comment: PPTP has many known vulrenabilities, it is no longer recommended for use...

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of Ubuntu that you're using so we can better troubleshoot your issue.